# how to calculate the parallel and serial portion of code?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a code that I wrote using OpenMP and C++ and I want to know how much of it is serial and parallel.
I read about some speedup ratio laws and formulas but I don't know how to calculate the percentage of the parallel code and the serial code
and if someone could guide me to some free software and a website that would help me draw the speedup ratio for cores 1-8

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

int userInput(int num) {
    const int len = num;
    return len;
}


void main() {

    long double dataSetOneSum = 0, dataSetTwoSum = 0, multiplicationSum = 0, setOnePowSum = 0, setTwoPowSum = 0;
    long double correlationCoefficient;

    int i;
    int num;
    cout << "enter size of data sets: " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    int length = userInput(num);

    double wtime;
    long double* dataSetOne = new long double[length];
    long double* dataSetTwo = new long double[length];
    long double* dataSetMultiplication = new long double[length];
    long double* dataSetOnePow = new long double[length];
    long double* dataSetTwoPow = new long double[length];


    srand(time(0));

    omp_set_num_threads(3);
    wtime = omp_get_wtime();



#pragma omp parallel for
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            dataSetOne[i] = 1 + (rand() % 99);
            cout << "thread num: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
        }
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            dataSetOneSum = dataSetOneSum + dataSetOne[i];
            //cout << "thread num: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
        }
        cout << "the sum of the first data set :" << fixed << dataSetOneSum << endl;

#pragma omp parallel for
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            dataSetTwo[i] = 1 + (rand() % 99);
            //cout << "thread num: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
        }
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            dataSetTwoSum = dataSetTwoSum + dataSetTwo[i];
            //cout << "thread num: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
        }

        cout << "the sum of the second data set :" << dataSetTwoSum << endl;;
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (i = 0;i < length;i++) {
            dataSetMultiplication[i] = dataSetOne[i] * dataSetTwo[i];
            multiplicationSum = multiplicationSum + dataSetMultiplication[i];
            //cout << "thread num: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
        }

        cout << "the sum of the two data sets multiplied  : " << multiplicationSum << endl;
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (i = 0;i < length;i++) {
            dataSetOnePow[i] = pow(dataSetOne[i], 2);
            setOnePowSum = setOnePowSum + dataSetOnePow[i];
            //cout << "thread num: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
        }

        cout << "the sum of the first data set numbers raised to the power of 2  : " << setOnePowSum << endl;
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (i = 0;i < length;i++) {
            dataSetTwoPow[i] = pow(dataSetTwo[i], 2);
            setTwoPowSum = setTwoPowSum + dataSetTwoPow[i];
            //cout << "thread num: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
        }

        cout << "the sum of the second data set numbers raised to the power of 2  : " << setTwoPowSum << endl;

        correlationCoefficient = ((length * multiplicationSum) - (dataSetOneSum * dataSetTwoSum)) / (sqrt((length * setOnePowSum) - (pow(dataSetOneSum, 2))) * sqrt((length * setTwoPowSum) - (pow(dataSetTwoSum, 2))));

        cout << "the correlation = " << correlationCoefficient << endl;

        if (correlationCoefficient > 0) {
            cout << "the correlation between data sets is: " << correlationCoefficient << ",  data sets is positively correlated " << endl;
        }
        else if (correlationCoefficient == 0) {
            cout << "the correlation between datasets is: " << correlationCoefficient << ",  data sets is independent" << endl;
        }
        else if (correlationCoefficient < 0) {
            cout << "the correlation between data sets is: " << correlationCoefficient << ",  data sets is negatively correlated " << endl;
        }
        wtime = omp_get_wtime() - wtime;
        cout << "  Elapsed wall clock time = " << wtime << "\n";
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: If you care about speed, use `x*x` not `pow(x, 2)`

Comment: @BenVoigt well, thank you but it's kinda hard to edit the code now since i have to submit it as a project and i don't want any more errors, i just want to draw the speed up ratio

Comment: If you change `omp_set_num_threads(3);` from being hard-coded to being an input (I think if you leave it out, it automatically uses the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable?), then measure the run time with different core counts, you'll have the data you're supposed to graph.  From that graph you should be able to estimate serial and parallel fractions.

Comment: @BenVoigt actually that was for testing, at the end i might change that line of code

Comment: @BenVoigt i did test the program with different core counts and i do have the data but i dont know how to draw the graph, have any ideas?

Comment: For making the graph you have many good options: gnuplot, or excel, or matlab, or pgfplots

Comment: Please note that your code is full of race conditions.

Comment: @Zulan: He needs "reduce" clauses, right?